# does going to the itunes store app to sign out also sign you out of your icloud account?

Tags: profile-manager

I have an iPhone 4 with an IOS all the way up to date and I got it from my older brother as a birthday present. He moved to college and isn't in contact. I have my own Apple I'd and thought about using it but I don't want to go to the iTunes app and sign out of his account from the bottom where the balance is shown because I don't want it to be signed in but asking for the old password. What should I do?

Also will that sign me out of his cloud account? I have a broken iPhone and want to get the stuff off of my cloud account

Comment: If you want to leave his account, then create a new account for you.

Comment: I don't want to delete his cloud account but I want to sign out of his and into mine

Comment: What is keeping you from signing out?

Answer (score 1):

if you sign out of iTunes / App Store, than won't disconnect you from iCloud and vise versa